# IE8 width conditional

Tags: internet-explorer, width

I'm working in IE8.

I've got a div whose width depend of the content. The width as a minimum size. but if the content is larger than the min, the width should be 123px.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <STYLE type="text/css">
.elements{
    max-width:200px;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="elements">
 100px
</div>
<br/>
<div class="elements">
    Content too long, should be 200px
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bH7mZ/3/

The first div should be 100px and the second 200px.

Comment: Sorry to be "that guy" but why? Why are you supporting a browser that is 2 generations out of date and will account for less than 2% of installed users by years end. Not to mention jQuery is dropping support for it by year's end and it doesn't support W3 consortium HTML standards or CSS3.

Comment: sorry to be "that guy" but IE is full use in many enterprise and government. There's still a lot(not that much) people who use IE8 and as developer your website should be for everyone. And I NEED to make it working on IE8.